# How filter dropdown options based on another dropdown selection in Magento2 UI grid filters

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent, ui

I am struck in finding the solution for the below requirements

Assume drop down#1 and drop down#2 selection box in the Magento2 admin UI grid filters. If we select option in one drop down#1 then we have to filter option in drop down#2 based on drop down#1 selection value.

If anyone aware of the solution / any alternate to achieve this requirement, please help to share your feedback / suggestion.

[image]

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer just a concept and i don't have enough time to provide full example, but hope this will help to understand a concept.

**1. Custom Column Ui Component**

You need to create a custom column element for your second filter and extend for example `Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select`. You still can use native template.

```js
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select',
    'uiRegistry',
    'underscore'
], function (Select, registry, _) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        defaults: {
            sourceFilter: '', // the name of primary filter
            sourceFilterUi: null,
            allOptions: [], // all available options
        },
        initConfig: function () {
            this._super();
            // maybe in some cases need to use defer for wait for element
            this.sourceFilterUi = registry.get(this.parent + '.' + this.sourceFilter);
            // store all options and reset applicable
            this.allOptions = this.options;
            this.options = [];
            // track source changes
            if (this.sourceFilterUi) {
                this.sourceFilterUi.value.subscribe(this.sourceChanged.bind(this));
            }
            // here you can add logic check source value and rebuild options (loaded from bookmark, etc)
        },
        sourceChanged: function(value) {
            // value might be undefined, string or array depends on parent source
            // store current value
            let old_value = this.values(), value;
            // generate applicable options
            let new options = [];
            _.each(this.allOptions, function(option) {
                if (option.parent == value) {
                    options.push(option);
                }
                if (old_value == option.value) {
                    value = option.value;
                }
            });


            // update options
            this.options(options);
            
            // restore value after update options
            if (value) {
                this.value(value);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**2. Filter in listing**

You need to define custom filter for listing and disable original filter

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="second_filter" provider="${ $.parentName }" 
                          component="Acme_StackExchange/js/grid/filters/elements/select-deps">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sourceFilter" xsi:type="string" translate="true">first_filter</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Second\Options"/>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </settings>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**3. Create custom options with relations**

```php
// ...
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    // ...
    public function toOptionArray(): array
    {
        return [
            [
                'label'  => __('Label'),
                'value'  => 'value',
                'parent' => 'parent',
            ],
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time and help Victor. Let me try and let you know. thanks once again.

Comment: Appreciate your help Victor. Your solution got worked. I just  fixed some issue in the code and posted below. I hope it will help others too.

Comment: I didn't have enough time to test and just wrote the concept here without testing ) and i'm happy that it works. Feel free to update question or my answer with working example. Please keep comments in comments

Comment: I can understand Victor. Thanks once again. Just posted the code with working examples.

Comment: Thank you, please update your answer with code block. Based on your answer, I found one critical typo mistake in my answer, just fixed typo. Hope this can also help anybody else.

Comment: Victort, I tried to make it multi select but not able to do figure the solution. Is it possible with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Victor, just refactored the code with working examples

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'uiRegistry',
        'underscore'
    ],
    function (Select, registry, _) {
        'use strict';
    
        return Select.extend({
            defaults: {
                parent: '${ $.parentName }',
                sourceFilter: '',
                sourceFilterUi: null,
                allOptions: []
            },
            initConfig: function () {
                this._super();
                this.sourceFilterUi = registry.get(this.parent+'.'+this.sourceFilter);
                this.allOptions = this.options;
                if (!this.sourceFilterUi || (this.sourceFilterUi == undefined)) {
                    return;
                }
                this.sourceFilterUi.value.subscribe(this.setFilteredOptions.bind(this));
            },
            setFilteredOptions: function (parent) {
                if (parent == undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                var filteredOptions = [];
                _.each(this.allOptions, function (option) {
                    if (option.parent == parent) {
                        filteredOptions.push(option);
                    }
                });
                this.options(filteredOptions);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks dottancohen for updated the block